# javaScript Slideshow doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I'm a relative beginner, I understand CSS and HTML but JS or jQuery happens mostly through copy and paste, so please be fair.

[www.iamreckoner.com/neuzwei](http://www.iamreckoner.com/neuzwei)

Here I have a slideshow implemented (works.js).

It works on Mozilla and Opera, on Safari it only shows the first 2 Images and then goes blank, sometimes this happens on Mozilla too. I already tried implementing a pre-loader but this didn't help. Has anybody an Idea? I copied the script from another page where it works  properly every time on all browsers and also  adapted my CSS. On preview mode in Dreamweaver it works without problems (exept Safari)

Here's my code after request, first the header then the first slideshow and the works.js
(which I copied unmodified from another page)

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="kiosk.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/works.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.localScroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js"></script>       

<div class="work" style="margin-left:10%; margin-top:100px;" data-date="2012" data-category="1">
    <div class="images" style="width:900px;height:600px;">
        <div>
            <img src="pic/f_i.jpg" style="width=:900px;height:600px"/>
            <img src="pic/f_cover.jpg" style="width=:900px;height:600px"/>
            <img src="pic/f_01.jpg" style="width=:900px;height:600px"/>
            <img src="pic/f_02.jpg" style="width=:900px;height:600px"/>
            <img src="pic/f_03.jpg" style="width=:900px;height:600px"/>
            <img src="pic/f_04.jpg" style="width=:900px;height:600px"/>
            <img src="pic/f_05.jpg" style="width=:900px;height:600px"/>
            <img src="pic/f_06.jpg" style="width=:900px;height:600px"/>
            <img src="pic/f_07.jpg" style="width=:900px;height:600px"/>
            <img src="pic/f_08.jpg" style="width=:900px;height:600px"/>
            <img src="pic/f_09.jpg" style="width=:900px;height:600px"/>
            <img src="pic/f_10.jpg" style="width=:900px;height:600px"/>
            <img src="pic/f_11.jpg" style="width=:900px;height:600px"/>
            <img src="pic/f_12.jpg" style="width=:900px;height:600px"/>
            <img src="pic/f_13.jpg" style="width=:900px;height:600px"/>
            <img src="pic/f_14.jpg" style="width=:900px;height:600px"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="text" style="width:700px;left:254px; position:absolute;">
        <p>Burkhardt Senger Fotografien — 78 pages, 170x250mm, 2012 </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the `works.js`

```
$(function() {
    var width = 0;
    $('.images img').each(function() {
        width += $(this).width();
    });

    $('.images div').css('width', width);

    $('.images div').each(function() {
        var images = $(this).children('img');
        if (images.length < 2) images.css('cursor', 'auto');
    });

    $('.images img').mousemove(function(e) {
        if (e.offsetX < $(this).width() / 2) {
            $(this).addClass('cursorLeft');     
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('cursorLeft');
        }
    }).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();  

        var currentImage = $(this).parent().parent().attr('data-current');

        if (currentImage == undefined) {
            currentImage = 0;
        }

        var images = $(this).parent().children('.images img');

        if (images.length < 2) return;

        if (e.offsetX < $(this).width() / 2) {
            if (currentImage == 0) {
                var pos = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < images.length-1; i++) {
                    pos += $(images[i]).width();
                }

                $(this).parent().animate({
                    left: -pos
                }, 250);
                currentImage = images.length - 1;
            } else {
                $(this).parent().animate({
                    left: '+='+$(images[currentImage]).width()
                }, 250);
                currentImage--; }       
            } else {
                if (currentImage == images.length - 1) {
                    $(this).parent().animate({
                        left: 0
                    }, 250);
                    currentImage = 0;
                } else {
                    $(this).parent().animate({
                        left: '-='+$(images[currentImage]).width()
                    }, 250);
                    currentImage++;
                }       
            }
            $(this).parent().parent().attr('data-current', currentImage);
        });

    function cleanMenu() {
        $('.menus .highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
    }

    $('.work .images, .work .text').mouseover(function() {
        var date       = $(this).parent().attr('data-date');
        var categories = $(this).parent().attr('data-category').split(',');

        cleanMenu();

        if (date < 2009) {
            $('#date_before').addClass('highlighted');      
        } else {
            $('#date_'+date).addClass('highlighted'); 
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
            $('#category_'+categories[i]).addClass('highlighted');  
        }
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        cleanMenu();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with your html

```
<img src="pic/f_07.jpg" style="width=:900px;height:600px"/>
```

change it to

```
<img src="pic/f_07.jpg" style="width:900px;height:600px;"/>
```

then check again and make sure path of images, js and css is correct.

Comment: thanks, i changed that for the first two slideshows to check but it still only shows the first two images.. the paths seem right, in preview it works fine in opera and mozilla..

Comment: change it in all slides as this is correct syntax and I try in chrome and it works for  me. Your live site is also not working in chrome.

Comment: changed in all slides... no change. the live site in mozilla works until the 5th or 6th image and then goes blank..maybe it loads the works script to early before all images are loaded?

Comment: have you changed it in live site?

Comment: i uploaded the new index.html,yes ... its iamreckoner.com/neuzwei

Comment: please check your code again. As I can see it is still  <img src="pic/f_cover.jpg" style="width=:900px;height:600px;"/>

Comment: excuse me i just looked after the semi-colons, not the equal signs...wait a minute.

Comment: wow, it seems that it is working! can you check it in chrome please?

Comment: awesome, thanks a lot! wouldve neve noticed this... since this is the internet i cant offer you a beer or so but have a nice weekend instead, thanks for helping!